# linking to a cell in a Notebook from an outside program

Tags: notebooks, files-and-directories

In MS OneNote I can link to a Paragraph, so that when I open that link from an external program (like Windows Explorer), it'll tell OneNote to open itself and then open that Paragraph.
I simply right-click on a Paragraph and it'll offer me to copy a link, which I can use externally.
Is there a way to get a link to a cell in Mathematica 12.1 like that?

Here's a video demonstration of what I don't know how to do in Mathematica:
https://www.loom.com/share/28f251e32e4940d49a124142a651a203

[it's kinda difficult to figure out whether Mathematice does not have a feature, when I'm unable at easily reading the documentation, as I'm completely new to it]

Comment: I don't think that this is possible in all the generality you want it. You can create such links for use within Mathematica, so you can create such links between several notebook documents. See e.g. the documentation for `NotebookLocate` and `CellTags` how to do that. Another thing you can do is to store your notebooks in the Wolfram cloud. Then you would have access to them via an URL, but would typically open them in the online version. It might be that I am mistaken and newer versions can do better than that, so I would suggest to wait for other answer/comments...

Comment: I can go the other way with SystemOpen, but not the direction you need. It would be very nice to be able to traverse in both directions.